MySqlServerVersion Error in .NET Core 3.1 in Startup.cs
I'm facing error: CS0246 in line new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 40)) 
The following is my Startup.cs:
using Enterprise.EmployeeManagement.DAL.Data;
using Enterprise.EmployeeManagement.Core.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Configure Entity Framework to use MySQL with Pomelo and MySqlConnector
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 40))  
            )
        );

        // Register the UserService as scoped
        services.AddScoped<UserService>();

        // Add controllers with views
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
           https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}

The following packages seems to be disabled/grey in the editor:
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage;


I'm using .NET Core 3.1 (strictly the same version), Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.2.7
Using Three Tier Architecture with Core, DAL and Web Layers (Startup.cs exists in WEb Layer)

I tried doing following things:

Tried reinstalling the packages with the required version and made sure they are in Dependency/Packages in Web Layer
Tried dotnet clean , dotnet build , dotnet resotre serveral times.


There's no point trying to find a solution for .NET Core 3.1. It's way beyond End Of Life and many libraries already dropped support for it. Even .NET 6 reached EOL. The oldest Long Term Support version is .NET 8.

The class MySqlServerVersion was first added in Pomelo v5. If you try to change the branch to a v3 tag you'll get a 404 error. It seems you tried to copy code from a recent project into a 3.1 project. The real solution is to migrate the project to .NET 8. The stopgap is to use the Action<MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilder> option of UseMySql to set the server version as a string. Whether that works with MySQL 8 and a 4-year old MySqlConnector ....

The 3.0 version of Pomelo is tied to pre-1.0 versions of MySqlConnector too. The newest version it can use is 0.69.10, last released in 2020. That's 4 years of missing bugs and problems.

The newer MySqlServerVersion class, introduced in later Pomelo versions(e.g 5.0.0 can work fine). In older versions(3.2.7), the MySqlServerVersion may not work as directly. You can specify the server version as a string like below:
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.ServerVersion("8.0.40-mysql"))            
    );


This is just a stopgap though. The old Pomelo version is tied to an old MySqlConnector version. It's not just the unsupported .NET Core runtime, there are 3 years of bugs that weren't fixed in the discontinued versions
